# HTML using input pattern for input of integer from -99 to 99 (optional negative mark)

Tags: html

I would like to allow my input box in HTML to receive only integers from `-99` to `99`,
but if I use `pattern="[-][0-9][0-9]{2,3}"` or `[-0-9]|[0-9]{2,3}` or anything similar it allows the user to place from `-99` too `999`.

How can I make this negative sign `-` only optionally at the front of the introduced digit?
I.e. either the user will use it at the beginning of the introduced value, and if not, max 2 digits in a whole (above 0) value.

Comment: You most likely are going to need to use the `type="number"` or `type="range"` -- Both which will allow what you are looking for without a complicated regex pattern .. Which also my not be absolute in all cases. ((browser type, OS etc etc)

Answer (score 2):

First, you could use `type="number"` with `min` and `max` attributes, which would probably be the best option.

Alternatively, the right pattern is `-?[0-9]{1,2}`.

- `-` is a literal minus sign (no need to enclose it in brackets)
- `?` means the previous atom (in this case the minus sign) is optional
- `[0-9]{1,2}` means one or two digits, so anything from 0 to 99 (including 00, 01…)

Comment: That's it! Had to use type="integer" cause of Spring, but your pattern works perfectly. Dunno why I foundly only syntax of (:x:)? or (x)? where x was optional - yet it was so simple! All the best, mate! So happy for such quick response!

Comment: May I have one more question - what about a case where I would allow inputs -99.9 to 99.9? Tried `-?[0-9]{1,2}.[0-9]{1}` but when I put 9999 it saves as 9999.0 anyway, not limited to 99.9 or so. Also couldn't find way to make `.x` as optional - adding `?` doesn't help in this case.

Comment: I believe type="number" with step="0.1" should be the simplest, but otherwise pattern="-?[0-9]{1,2}(?:\.[0-9])?" should work